Keyboard locked after update system to 22.04 LTS
I can't use Ubuntu any more because my keyboard do not react while on windows the is no problem.
With Linux when I go trying to get a proposed upgrade with the mouse I can type my asked password but when I type the Enter key this one in refused.
I tried also with the virtual keyboard same problem.
So I do not know what to do.
I am totaly stranded with linux Ubuntu ver: 22.04.4LTS
Regards.
Eric Frere Bruxelles.

push ALT+F2 in there login, use the df -h does it show any thing that is 100% use% if it does edit your question with the info. Do not write in comment.
